# how to calculate how much time has passed when I registered such an item in the database

Tags: javascript

```
const getHoursOrMinutesAgo = (createdAtNanos) => {
    console.log(createdAtNanos)
    const now = moment();
    const createdAtMilliseconds = createdAtNanos / 1000000; 
    const createdAt = moment(createdAtMilliseconds);
        
    const duration = moment.duration(now.diff(createdAt));
        
    const hoursAgo = duration.hours();
    const minutesAgo = duration.minutes();
    const secondsAgo = duration.seconds();
    
    if (hoursAgo > 0) {
       return `${hoursAgo} hora(s) atrás`;
    } else if (minutesAgo > 0) {
       return `${minutesAgo} minuto(s) atrás`;
    } else {
       return `${secondsAgo} segundo(s) atrás`;
    }
};
```

I don't know how to explain, please help me with that, i want just calculate how much time passed with a nanoseconds parameter

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get an error message? Is the calculated time different from what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Use `moment.utc()` to ensure that you're working in the UTC timezone, since UNIX timestamps are in UTC.
You should directly use the `asHours(), asMinutes(), and asSeconds()` methods of `moment.duration` to handle cases where the elapsed time might be more than 24 hours, 60 minutes, or 60 seconds.

Your code should be :

```
const getHoursOrMinutesAgo = (createdAtNanos) => {
    const now = moment.utc();
    const createdAtMilliseconds = createdAtNanos / 1000000;
    const createdAt = moment.utc(createdAtMilliseconds);
        
    const duration = moment.duration(now.diff(createdAt));

    const hoursAgo = Math.floor(duration.asHours());
    const minutesAgo = Math.floor(duration.asMinutes()) % 60; // modulus to get remaining minutes
    const secondsAgo = Math.floor(duration.asSeconds()) % 60; // modulus to get remaining seconds
    
    if (hoursAgo > 0) {
       return `${hoursAgo} hora(s) atrás`;
    } else if (minutesAgo > 0) {
       return `${minutesAgo} minuto(s) atrás`;
    } else {
       return `${secondsAgo} segundo(s) atrás`;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hello! The code that u send me returned this "470858 hours ago" and i just created the data... This is my createdAt value = {
    "seconds": 1695090332,
    "nanoseconds": 524000000
}